# Unity3d render texture based on position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to create a container in Unity with multiple quads inside, and am looking for a way to stop parts of the quad that fall outside of the containers bounds from being rendered?

I just spent twenty minutes trying to fiqure out how to explain the problem properly (and failed) so created this pretty picture instead. The red line represents the bounds with the black squares representing my textured quads.

[image]

Comment: Make sure to post up on Unity answers, you're more likely to get a response there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do

Comment: Your question is a little light on details.  Are you doing this all on a texture or are the quads actual meshes in Unity?  If meshes, you either need to do the math to slice your out-of-bounds quads or use a shader to set out-of-bounds pixels to transparent.  Neither option is easy to express in an SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private Rect ClipRectToScreen (Rect input)
                    {
                            // Special handling for screen reading of render texture so it always stay in visible area.
                            // Will throw error withoud this fix.
                            Rect r;
                            r = new Rect (input.x, (Screen.height - input.y - input.height) , input.width, input.height);
                            if (r.x < 0f) {
                                    r.width = r.width - UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs (r.x);
                                    r.x = 0f;
    //                              Debug.Log ("x < 0");
                            }
                            if (r.y < 0f) {
                                    r.height = r.height - UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs (r.y);
                                    r.y = 0f;
    //                              Debug.Log ("y < 0");
                            }
                            if (r.x > Screen.width) {
                                    r.width = r.width - UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs (r.x);
                                    r.x = 0f;
    //                              Debug.Log ("x > Screen.width");
                            }
                            if (r.y > Screen.height) {
                                    r.height = r.height - UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs (r.y);
                                    r.y = 0f;
    //                              Debug.Log ("y > Screen.height");
                            }
                            if ((r.x + r.width) > Screen.width) {
                                    r.width = Screen.width - r.x;
    //                              Debug.Log ("r.x + r.width > Screen.width");
                            }
                            if ((r.y + r.height) > Screen.height) {
                                    r.height = Screen.height - r.y;
    //                              Debug.Log ("r.y + r.height > Screen.height");
                            }

                            return r;
                    }
```